# no matching function for call to ‘glutinit’ error in Xcode

Tags: opengl

I am having trouble with this because in Xcode, when I make the change, I get an error :

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Why is this happening?

When you create a default project in Cocoa template of Xcode the main function is generated accordion to the following:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
```

You can solve this if you review your main-function and remove "const" from the following main function:

```
 int main(int argc, char * argv[])
```

and build again.

Comment: C & C++ are case-sensitive: `glutinit` != `glutInit`.

Comment: I phrased my question wrong. I have glutInit however, it does not recognize it. By taking the const out of the argv, the error goes away but it does not compile and gives the error 


clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)